# how do I render a handlebars page from a routing module

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning nodejs with express platform. I generated an express project and there are 2 routing files that I edited. One routing file is "users.js" and it's supposed to render layou.hbs when '/users' is requested, the other is "index.js" and it's supposed to render "home.hbs" when '/' is requested. the problem is, when '/' is requested on the url box, i get layout.hbs output on the browser. What am i doing wrong?
Here is the code from the files.

1. index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', {title:Express});
});
module.exports = router;
```

2. user.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('layout', {title:Express});
   //res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

3. Home.hbs

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>goodbye World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

4. layout.hbs

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <p> Hello World!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

if i visit localhost:3000, I expect to see "goodbye world" but I see "hello world", what is wrong with this code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In both the files you are rendering 'home'. In line  `res.render('home', {title:Express});`

In user.js do this:

```
res.render('layout', {title:Express});
```

Cheers:)

Comment: I fixed that, but the problem is the output still says "hello world" instead of "goodbye world" when I visit home directory

Comment: please change the title also.

Comment: My bad i miss typed, change location of your folder

Comment: check your static folder is exact

Answer (score 0):

You should remember to require express-hbs and tell express to use that. Your main app.js or any other names you gave that file should look like this.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var hbs = require('express-hbs'); //load handlebars
var app = express();

// setup hbs view engine 
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//location of your views folder
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever template you render, it will be loaded as the body of your layout. For this to work, your layout should look like:

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

The actual body contents should go in the template you render

home.hbs

```
  <p> Hello World!</p>
```

goodbye.hbs

```
  <p> Goodbye World!</p>
```

So doing

```
 res.render('home');
```

Would show "hello world" whereas rendering

```
 res.render('goodbye');
```

Would display "Goodbye world"

If you wanted to use a different layout to wrap a given template, you can override the default:

```
  res.render('other', {layout: 'other_layout'});
```

BTW, passing the variable "title" as

```
 {title: Express}
```

Means nothing. The "Express" variable isn't declared. You should instead use a defined variable or pass a string literal

```
 {title: 'Express'}
```

And, to have it displayed in the generated HTML, the layout would use it like this:

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>

 {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

Please note the body part has 3 curly braces whereas the template vars use only 2.